# Etherpad-lite: Why is websocket handshake failing?

Tags: node.js, apache, mod-proxy, etherpad

I have Etherpad-lite operational, with [Apache mod_proxy](https://github.com/ether/etherpad-lite/wiki/How-to-put-Etherpad-Lite-behind-a-reverse-Proxy#very-basic-rewrite) to pass requests to it on the same domain. This all works fine on our dev server, but on production, the websocket handshake fails. Chrome reports:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://example.com/Sg7qfKT2_pad/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=UzTXyLsuzz2UMBmmAAAG' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400

This failures leaves no immediate errors in apache or etherpad-lite logs. Just to rub in this failure, Etherpad successfully falls back to long polling but gives a session cookie that expires in only 3 minutes, dumping you to an error.

How can I debug what's happening here?

If I can't resolve this, can I at least increase the Expires age on the `sessionID` cookie, so users stopped getting booted for no good reason?

**Update:** The prod server is Apache 2.2, but we may have to upgrade it to install `mod_proxy_wstunnel`

Comment: Steve, did you found a solution?

Comment: Follow-up: Are you running it behind `Apache`? Just solved this issue in my environment, but I'm using `Nginx`.